# Associating (has_one) multiple models in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm unable to associate the foreign key before saving the data (the field 'user_id' for the Network model is blank when stored in the database). I'm new to RoR so please excuse me if my code is sloppy :-)

Models:

```
class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one  :network, :foreign_key => "user_id",
                   :dependent => :destroy
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
  @user = User.new
  @network = @user.build_network
  @title = "Sign Up"
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if (@user.save)
    @network = Network.new(params[:network])
    if (@network.save)
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  else
    @title = "Sign up"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

I'm able to get all of the user input from the view without issues (using form_for and fields_for). Do I have to explicitly define the has_one association in addition to using @user.build_network ?

Per the suggestion of using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, I cleaned up my controller to be

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_network
  @title = "Sign Up"
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if (@user.save)
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
    redirect_to @user        
  else
    @title = "Sign up"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

The updated association in the User Model:

```
has_one  :network, :class_name => 'Network',
         :foreign_key => "user_id",
         :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :network,
                              :reject_if => :all_blank,
                              :allow_destroy => true
```

However, the network_attributes are all blank when I submit the form. I have followed the directions in the links provided as well as http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes (and many more)

I don't think it's an issue with the view/form since I'm able to access the attributes using `Network.new(params[:network]`

Any thoughts/suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect situation for using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html as well as http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for to see how you can easily implement it using `form_for`

---

(post-question update)

If you can access the attributes for `Network` through `params[:network]`, then you have (unfortunately!) missed one of the more subtle parts of nested attributes, which is the invocation of `fields_for`

I'm assuming you have something along the lines of the following (using HAML syntax for speed):

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.text_field :email_address

  - fields_for @network do |n|
    = n.text_field :name
```

The problem with this is that Rails isn't seeing any explicit connection in the form between your `User` and `Network` fields. (It's smart, but not *that* smart)

The way you explicitly state that `Network` is nested within `User` (for the sake of updating nested attributes is to make sure you call the `fields_for @network` function on the **`User`** form builder, not by itself:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.text_field :email_address

  - f.fields_for @network do |n|
    = n.text_field :name
```

That way, when you submit your form and inspect `params`, you'll notice that you've got both `params[:user]` and `params[:user][:network]` - which Rails will recognise as nested attributtes and *should* then save them and link them together.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have updated the question as I'm still having issues with the Network attributes saving.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible you need to set network as attr_accessible, along with other attributes of User model, like this:

`attr_accessible :name, :age, :network_attributes, ...`

Please note you'll also need to put all attributes you want to 'mass assign' in the list, just like :name and :age in the above example.